# error occurred while closing itext stamper

Tags: itext

I'm receiving an error when closing itextpdf stamper. Stamper is used for setting password for PDF file. application is deployed in weblogic server. Itextpdf5.5.10 is used.

```
OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("/apps/abc.pdf");
            System.out.println(reader.getNumberOfPages());
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream, '\0');
            stamper.setEncryption("abc".getBytes(), "123".getBytes(),
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
            stamper.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please, help. :(

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: ... including its stack trace, please.

Comment: Thanks Joe & mkl, I corrected the issue. Issue was a nullpointerexception when stamping close. I have mistakenly not initialized the fileoutputstream. that was the issue.